# how to instantiate the variable you passed in the constructor in Laravel Jobs

Tags: php, oop, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-jobs

I created a protected $companyID; in my Job class then in the `__construct` function I passed an `$id` but when I try to instantiate the variable in my `handler function` its `null`

```
protected $companyID = NULL;

public function __construct($ID) {
    $this->companyID = $ID;
}
```

Then when instantiating the class?

```
    $ProcessOutgoingSMS = new ProcessOutgoingSMS();
    $ProcessOutgoingSMS->dispatch(3);
```

Comment: Take a look at thi link https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-do-you-pass-constructor-parameters-when-youre-instantiating-an-interface-through-a-bind

Answer (score 1):

You should pass 3 into constructor:

```
$ProcessOutgoingSMS = new ProcessOutgoingSMS(3);
$ProcessOutgoingSMS->dispatch();
```

and not

```
$ProcessOutgoingSMS = new ProcessOutgoingSMS();
$ProcessOutgoingSMS->dispatch(3);
```

Comment: Thanks Marcin, but moved the injection from the actual class to the dispatch method as a means of testing did not see that had left it there, did try that solution but could not win

Answer (score 0):

You don't pass any argument to the constructor, maybe this is the source of your problem.

```
$ProcessOutgoingSMS = new ProcessOutgoingSMS(2);
```

---

As more a general code style comment, I would also recommend not having variables with uppercase first characters. `$id` and `$processOutgoingSMS`.

Comment: I get AsTeR but now the issue is since am trying to inject the value in the console/Kernel.php as I need to run multiple jobs for different companyID's at different now need to inject those id's so that when by default I call 
php artisan queue:work all my jobs can run.

Answer (score -1):

Where I instantiate the class and try to perform the injection console/kernel.php

```
$idobject = (object)['id' => 3];
new ProcessOutgoingSMS($idobject);
```

then in the class which am trying to perform the functionality made the var a static var

```
static $companyID = 0;
```

now the constructor looks like

```
public function __construct($company) {
    self::$companyID = $company->id;
}
```

then in the handle() function I can access whatever value was injected

```
dd(self::$companyID);
```

thanks guys